# Daily Calendar View

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to have an easy customized DAILY calander view.

I have been looking for one but with no success...

Do you maybe know about one?

Thank you!

Comment: Customized how?  And are you referring to a built-in calendar app, or a custom one?

Comment: I want to be able to change the hours (instead 24, 10, like school hours), and to add events...
As far as I know there isn't built-in calendar app... So I mean the custom one xD

Comment: I find it a little hard to believe that there isn't a calendar/organizer app on the phone.  Besides which, wouldn't it be able to integerate with the google calendar that's part of GMail - or at the very least, access it on the web?  Irregardless, I'm afraid this may be closed, as it doesn't appear to be a programming question (application request) - try [AndroidEnthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I didnt ask for an application... I asked for a view (like button, textbox,layout etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to make a table layout and with some textviews to get the same result...